# Automatically Adding "/homepage" in all landing pages in Google analytics reports

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Though there is no redirection not any error in landing pages.
But in reporting, while selecting landing pages against source of traffic, every landing page ends with "/homepage"
EG :

google / organic |
http://www.knexusgroup.com/show/blog/successful-business-to-business-marketing-campaigns**/homepage**

This "/homepage" is coming on all landing pages of websites.

how to solve this problem to get correct data in analytics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics logging and is not programing related.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check Default page value in View Settings. It may have /homepage there, remove it.